# Android: Layout short within a ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I recently just overhauled my application to use ListView instead of using the classic TextView.setText and looping the inflation of a layout. I was able to acheive this very well but now I'm having a problem having it fill the screen. Heres the section of my code that does the work.

```
        //Place JSON data into array one item at a time
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        //Loop through each record in the database
        //Get ListView
        ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // create the grid item mapping
        String[] from = new String[] {"lblQuote", "lblBuzzed", "lblShared", "lblSaid", "lblLikes", "lblHates", "lblLocation", "lblDate"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.lblQuote, R.id.lblBuzzed, R.id.lblShared, R.id.lblSaid, R.id.lblLikes, R.id.lblHates, R.id.lblLocation, R.id.lblDate };

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            Log.i("uDrew Debug", "Made it into JSONArray Loop");

            //Get this record
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //Put each result into variables for later handling
            strFName = json_data.getString("FName");
            strLInitial = json_data.getString("LInitial");
            strCity = json_data.getString("City");
            strState = json_data.getString("State");
            strDate = json_data.getString("Date");
            strQuote = json_data.getString("Quote");
            intLikes = Integer.parseInt(json_data.getString("Likes"));
            intHates = Integer.parseInt(json_data.getString("Hates"));
            strFNameSaid = json_data.getString("FNameSaid");
            strLInitialSaid = json_data.getString("LInitialSaid");
            intBuzz = Integer.parseInt(json_data.getString("Buzz"));


            Log.i("uDrew Debug", "Made it past JSON Parsing");


            switch(intBuzz){
                case 1: 
                    strBuzzed = ("One Beer\nSyndrome");
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    strBuzzed = ("Buzzed");
                    break;
                 case 3: 
                     strBuzzed = ("Drunk");
                    break;
                 case 4: 
                     strBuzzed = ("Trashed");
                    break;
                 case 5: 
                    strBuzzed = "Retarded";
                    break;
            }                       
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("lblQuote", strQuote);
            map.put("lblBuzzed", strBuzzed);
            map.put("lblShared", strFName + " " + strLInitial);
            map.put("lblSaid",strFNameSaid + " " + strLInitialSaid);
            map.put("lblDate", strDate);
            map.put("lblLocation", strCity + ", " + strState);
            map.put("lblLikes", intLikes.toString());
            map.put("lblHates", intHates.toString());
            fillMaps.add(map);



        }//End For loop
     // fill in the grid_item layout
     SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.myviews, from, to);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:id="@+id/myMainLayout" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
              <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adViewer"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="a14de539f600385"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:text="RandomDrunkQuotes.com" 
            android:id="@+id/lblTitle" 
            android:textSize="16px" 
            android:padding="5px" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <!-- List Divider -->
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

myviews.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblQuote" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Filler Text"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left">
           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:paddingRight="5px"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbsup"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblLikes" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:paddingRight="5px"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="10"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblBuzzedTitle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="Buzz Level:"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblShared" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Shared By: Filler Name"
                android:textSize="4pt"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblSaid" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Said By: Filler Name"
                android:textSize="4pt"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:paddingRight="5px"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbsdn"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
          <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblHates" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:paddingRight="5px"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblBuzzed" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="High"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblDate" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="04/04/1987 4:32 PM"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblLocation" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="Broomfield, CO"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">
          <TextView
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="1pt"
            android:background="#6F7285"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>  

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Heres what the App looks like:
[image]

There are also no scrollbars and if I change the main.xml ScrolView layout_height="fill_parent" it extends to the end of the screen but the scrollable option isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed my problem:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/BigLayout" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/myMainLayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">   

        <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adViewer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="a14de539f600385"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:text="RandomDrunkQuotes.com" 
            android:id="@+id/lblTitle" 
            android:textSize="16px" 
            android:padding="5px" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <!-- List Divider -->
        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />       

    </LinearLayout>

        <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </ListView>     

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in your ScrollView and in the first LinearLayout.
2. Don't wrap the ListView inside a LinearLayout (the one below the divider View). There's absolutely no need for that.
3. (Optional) you might want to move the AdView outside the ScollView so it is always visible and not scrolled away

Comment: I've done 1 and 2 and now my scroll bars don't exist but the content fills the screen.

Comment: Anyone I'd love any offered help.

Comment: @O1DMBFan does it scroll? did you try android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"?

Comment: Thanks for the Response first off. It does not scroll. I've added the line you've provided to the ScrollView. This shows the scroll bar on the right when you load it and then fades away but I still can't scroll the content.